# Motivation for introducing von Neumann algebra in addition to $C^*$algebra

Tags: mathematical-physics

Observables are self-adjoint elements of a $C^*$algebra. As such, this structure seems sufficient to describe physics.

A theorem by Gelfand and Naimark says that a [$C^*$algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C*-algebra) can always be faithfully represented as bounded operators on a Hilbert space, $B(H)$. Then one can introduces different topologies, and one can see [von Neumann algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_algebra) as a $C^*$subalgebra of $B(H)$ that is moreover complete in one of those topologies.

In another question of Physics stack exchange https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2043/2451 someone also talks about the Borel functional calculus, and one also compare von Neumann algebra to "non commutative" measure theory vs "non commutative" for $C^*$algebras.

My question is, is the introduction of von Neumann algebra only a technical thing or has it physical consequences? Or maybe more precisely, why is it important to consider several topologies on our algebra of operators?

ps: I posted the exact same question in physics, but it may be more relevant in math.

Comment: Perhaps this might help : www.math.bme.hu/~petz/2vn.pdf‎

Comment: the link didn't work

Comment: it did work finally, when I type the "2vn.pdf" instead of pasting it...

Answer (score 1):

There are many $C^*$-algebras, but only few vNa in comparison. $C^*$-algebras are more difficult to understand.

Example: Commutative $C^*$-algebras correspond to locally compact Hausdorff spaces, commutative vNA's to measure spaces, which are all isomorphic to the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ plus counting measure on a discrete set.

Answer (score 0):

One consequence of being complete under various topologies, is that one can approximate an element of the von Neumann algebra by converging sequences from a dense subsets. But I guess that the more topologies such that our vN algebra is complete, the more possible dense subsets we have.